# How to form a dictionary from a string?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

```
word = 'stacks' 
word_dict = {} # to form new dictionary formed from
for letter in word:
    word_dict[letter] += 1
print word_dict
```

I want to create a new dictionary from a string, tracking the count of the letters from `word`. So what I'm trying to get is:

```
> word_dict = {'s':2, 't':1, 'a':1, 'c':1, 'k':1}
```

But I can't figure out how to do this. I get `KeyError` with my current code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting each letter's frequency in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806866/counting-each-letters-frequency-in-a-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`collections.Counter()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead:

```
from collections import Counter

word_dict = Counter(word)
```

The `Counter` does the exact same thing; count occurrences of each letter in `word`.

In your specific case you didn't first check if the key already exists or provide a default if it doesn't. You could use `dict.get()` to do that:

```
word = 'stacks' 
word_dict = {} # to form new dictionary formed from
for letter in word:
    word_dict[letter] = word_dict.get(letter, 0) + 1
print word_dict
```

or use `dict.setdefault()` separately to explicitly set a default before incrementing:

```
word = 'stacks' 
word_dict = {} # to form new dictionary formed from
for letter in word:
    word_dict.setdefault(letter, 0)
    word_dict[letter] += 1
print word_dict
```

or test for the key yourself:

```
word = 'stacks' 
word_dict = {} # to form new dictionary formed from
for letter in word:
    if letter not in word_dict:
        word_dict[letter] = 0
    word_dict[letter] += 1
print word_dict
```

in decreasing order of efficiency.

Or you could use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to automatically insert a `0` if there the key doesn't yet exist:

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_dict = defaultdict(int)
for letter in word:
    word_dict[letter] += 1
print word_dict
```

This is essentially what the `Counter` class does, but the type adds some other niceties such as listing the most common keys or combining counters.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> word = 'stacks' 
>>> word_dict = {} # to form new dictionary formed from
>>> for letter in word:
...     word_dict[letter] = word_dict.get(letter, 0) + 1
... 
>>> word_dict
{'a': 1, 'c': 1, 's': 2, 't': 1, 'k': 1}
>>> word_dict = defaultdict(int)
>>> for letter in word:
...     word_dict[letter] += 1
... 
>>> word_dict
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 1, 'c': 1, 's': 2, 't': 1, 'k': 1})
>>> Counter(word)
Counter({'s': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 1, 't': 1, 'k': 1})
```

Comment: is it possible to do this in a for loop? I just started learning Python

Comment: @AlanH: I covered all the bases here for you.

Comment: There is also  `word_dict.setdefault(letter, 0)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: but that won't let you use it in one line. `dict.setdefault()` is *great* when using a mutable type like a list or a set or a dictionary though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. I did not realise doing it in one line was a requirement, I just thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: well, putting that on a separate line then use `word_dict[letter] += 1` on the next works but it's just not as neat as using `dict.get()` for this case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, true but I meant more in a general sense.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I've added in `dict.setdefault()` as well as an explicit key test case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from collections import Counter
>>>Counter(word)
Counter({'s': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 1, 't': 1, 'k': 1})
```

Comment: It should be `from collections import Counter`

Comment: confused with our great `packages` :)