# counting the amount of times a letter has appeared and then writing it to a list

Tags: python, list, counting

So basically as the title says, im try to count the amount of times a letter appears in a string. After counting them, i want them to print how many times the letters appears to the their respective number in a list.

```
t="QWERTYYQWERTYYY"
tList=[0]*26
lC=0
idx=0
for char in t:
   ch=ord(char)
    if ch >=65 and ch<=90 or ch >=97 and ch <= 122:
        lC=lC+1
        #I dont know what to do from here.

for ele in tList:
    print(idx, ": ", tList[]) #I dont know what to put in the brackets
    idx+=1
```

when I print lC, it tells me it has counted the amount of letters, but im struggling to print it to the according numbers on the idx list.

Comment: You need to convert from lower to upper case, or the reverse. I'd suggest you do that once, at the top of the loop:  `for char in t.upper():`. I'd further suggest you define `A = ord('A')` and use that in your math. Possibly also `Z`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting each letter's frequency in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806866/counting-each-letters-frequency-in-a-string)

Comment: Since you have parentheses after your `print`s, I assume you're using Python 3.x. In that case, use `str.casefold()` rather than converting to lower/upper case. Then you can match unicode! E.g. `"Gß".casefold() == "gss"; True`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a very Pythonic approach. If you don't have the requirement to "do everything yourself," then:

```
from collections import Counter

t="QWERTYYQWERTYYY"
info = Counter(t)
for char, count in info.items():
    print('Letter {0} occurred {1} times'.format(char, count))
```

Output:

```
Letter W occurred 2 times
Letter T occurred 2 times
Letter R occurred 2 times
Letter E occurred 2 times
Letter Q occurred 2 times
Letter Y occurred 5 times
```

Without using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) you could make things easier by using a dictionary; this will handle the mapping of a character to a value for how many times it has occurred:

```
t="QWERTYYQWERTYYY"
info = {}
for char in t:
    if char in info:
        info[char] += 1
    else:
        info[char] = 1
```

You could iterate this dictionary the same as the Counter example to produce your output.

**TL;DR**

A list is the wrong data structure to use here, you want a dictionary.

Comment: Im sorry to be so noobish, but what does it mean when you put: info={}

Comment: No need to be sorry! ```info = {}``` is binding the variable 'info' to a new dictionary. The use of '{}' is sort for calling 'dict()'. I.E. ```info = {}``` is the same as ```info = dict()```

Comment: ah okay. Thank you. Also, i know its not pythonic at all. My teacher wants us to be ready for java, so she has us doing it this way. Which isnt fun at all.

Comment: No problem. Even in Java, you would use something like a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) or [Dictionary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) to *store* an arbitrary relationship between two things. [Hashtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) are king of data structures for this type of thing; using multiple lists and indexes will be slower, more error prone, and harder to maintain (i.e. read/understand). But I know how teachers are sometimes... Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code a little to come up with the solution, or enough to get you going at least. I ran this in python 3.5.1 and it worked.

```
import json

t="QWERTYYQWERTYYY"
tList = list()

t_lower = t.lower()
character_found = False
character_count = 1

for char in t_lower:
    if char.isalpha():
        for item in tList:
            if char in item['character']:
                item['count'] += 1
                character_found = True
        if character_found:
            character_found = False
            continue
        else:
            tList.append( {'character': char,
                           'count' : character_count
                           } )
print (json.dumps(tList, indent=2, sort_keys = True))
```

The import json is there so I could print a nice output. Here's what it looks like:

```
    [
  {
    "character": "q",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "character": "w",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "character": "e",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "character": "r",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "character": "t",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "character": "y",
    "count": 5
  }
]
```

Edit: Use willnx's answer, way better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Make it easier with `dict`:

```
t="QWERTYYQWERTYYY"

count_dict = {}

#initialize dict
for char in set(t):
    count_dict[char] = 0

for char in t:
    ch = ord(char)
    if ch >=65 and ch<=90 or ch >=97 and ch <= 122:
        count_dict[char] += 1

print(count_dict)
```

It isn't perfect yet.

Init part apply `set` to the list to make it more efficient (loop less), try applying `set` to counting part.