# Determine that the word is from language with the help of stack

Tags: algorithm, stack

What is the algorithm for determining that the word is from a specific language with the help of the stack?

I know that I can put the word into stack symbol by symbol and while doing that I can record any needed info about symbols, but it will be no different from just iterating the word.

Comment: Why do you need to use the stack specifically? Are you trying to recall the name of a specific stack-based algorithm?

Comment: @doppelgreener, yep. I am sure that I used the algorithm, but can not recall it precisely.

Comment: How is the said language represented; as a regular expression; as a grammar?

Comment: @Codor, for example here is a languge:  { w : w is of the form A^nB^n, for some n >= 0 }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language is defined by a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), membership of a specific word can be determined efficiently by the so-called [CYK-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm).

The language given in the example above can be represented by the following context-free grammar where `epsilon` denotes the empty string.

```
S -> epsilon | aSb | ab
```

*Update*

For the CYK-algorithm to be applicable, the grammar needs to bein[Chomsky normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form); for the grammar above, this can be done as follows.

```
S -> epsilon | AT | AB
T -> SB
A -> a
B -> b
```

In this formulation, `A` and `B` are artificial nonterminal symbols for the terminal symbols `a` and `b`; `T` is an artificial variable introduced because each right-hand side may contain at most two nonterminal symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps for a start

- [LanguageIdentifier](http://www.lextek.com/langid/li/)
- [Rosette Language Identifier](http://www.basistech.com/language-identification/)

Other than that you could count the [frequency of the characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806866/counting-each-letters-frequency-in-a-string) composing the word and compare it to [frequency tables](https://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter20.html) of different languages to check (maybe this won't work for a single word but for a bunch of sentences it should work though)

Comment: Thank you very much for the attention. If no one else answers or if your answer will be the mot satisfying one I will accept it a bit later.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped so far.