# Collapse duplicates in python list

Tags: python

sorry if this is a duplicate thread but I couldn't find one.

I'm currently trying to make an inventory for a game that is in the works. The problem I run into is that, when you have a lot of a particular item, it kind of wastes a lot of space.

Here's my code: (inv is the inventory)

```
inv = ["item1","item2","item3","item2","item2","item1"]

print(', '.join(inventory))
```

Output:

```
item1, item2, item3, item2, item2, item1
```

I'd like to, instead of doing that, do this:

```
item1 x2, item2 x3, item3
```

I don't really care if you need item3 to be x1, either way would be fine, thanks.

Comment: Where did the x2, x3 come from? There is no mention of it in your code? What is the idea behind what it is you are exactly trying to generate? What is the *problem* you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Well,  that's why I want it to do that... Please read my question over again :)

Comment: @idjaw: that's a "times 2" modifier.

Comment: Are you asking how to count objects?

Comment: Oh! I see it now. This looks like a job for `Counter`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829377/5139327

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806866/counting-each-letters-frequency-in-a-string

Answer (score 2):

There are many options actually. The main goal is to count your items, and print them out in order.

One option is to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Others are `collections.Counter`/`collections.defaultdict`, but I'll give you an example with the former:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

counter = OrderedDict()

inv = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item2", "item2", "item1"]
for i in inv:
    if i not in counter:
        counter[i] = 0

    counter[i] += 1

for c in counter:
    if counter[c] > 1:
        print(c + ' x{}'.format(counter[c]))
    else:
        print(c)
```

This prints:

```
item1 x2
item2 x3
item3
```

You're free to modify this example as needed if you want to print them out in one line. This code was written in python3.x.

Comment: @RyanTartaglia Quite so. If you're on python3, you can use `print(..., end=', ')`. If you're on python 2, first import print using `from __future__ import print_function` and do that.

Comment: @RyanTartaglia You'll have to do that in both print statements :)

Comment: @RyanTartaglia Noticed you revoked acceptance. What's wrong? Anything I can help with?

Comment: @RyanTartaglia Hey, no worries. As an asker you're not obligated to accept. But thank you for doing so. :)

Comment: Also, my bad... did mean to upvote your question before but it slipped my mind. Did it now.

Comment: @RyanTartaglia Yes... I have an idea you might be unknowingly using the same referenced list in multiple places... can't say without your code. Open a new question and put your code there and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @RyanTartaglia Was it a problem with my answer? Or how you adapted it? If it was the former, I won't stop you from unmarking it... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

inv = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item2", "item2", "item1"]

print (', '.join('%s x%d' % (item, count)
                 for item, count in sorted(Counter(inv).items())))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out = ['{} x{}'.format(item, inv.count(item)) if inv.count(item) > 1 else item 
   for item in set(inv)]
```

out:

```
['item1 x2', 'item2 x3', 'item3']
```

Comment: Same as Prune's answer, but less readable...

Comment: I'd tend to agree with @Coldspeed here. When you have to began splitting list comprehensions across several lines, you'd want to consider refactoring it into a vanilla `for` loop.

Comment: I think that's a valid point, I don't like taking up a lot of space for simple operations though