# How many times a substring appears in a string without using any count or other functions

Tags: python

I am trying to count the number of times a character appears in a string. For example, symbol `b` occurs 3 times in the string `abbcddba`.  However, my code below counts the length of the string instead.  For example, if I try to count how many times `b` appears in string `abbcddba`, it gives the count as `8`.

```
MyStr = input('Please enter a string: ')
symb = input('Which character you want to the count for: ')
count = 0
for i in range(0,len(MyStr)):
    if symb in MyStr:
        count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting each letter's frequency in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806866/counting-each-letters-frequency-in-a-string)

Comment: Is it a substring count or character count!?

Comment: basically, if the user inputs "apples for apples" as the string and then wants to check how many times "p" appeared in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This is a solution generic for finding the count of substring/character in a string

Keep checking is your symb is present in the start of Mystr and if found increment count and strip the symb at the beginning of MyStr, otherwise skip the first character and proceed!

```
>>> MyStr = 'thisishelloheyhihello'
>>> symb = 'hello'
>>> count=0
>>> while symb in MyStr:
...     if MyStr.startswith(symbol):
...             count+=1
...             MyStr = MyStr[MyStr.find(synb,2):]
...     else:MyStr=MyStr[1:]
... 
>>> print count
2
```

Using for loop:

```
>>> for i in range(len(MyStr)):
...     if MyStr[i:].startswith(symb):
...             count+=1
... 
>>> count
3
```

Comment: Where did `t` come from?

Comment: This seems like a pretty inefficient way to approach this problem since there's no need to modify the input string.

Comment: Not really. I've mentioned it. Its generic.

Comment: If the input string needs to be maintained, few modifications should do the trick!

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use a For loop :(

Comment: Also, I don't think `lstrip` works the way you intend here. For example, `'ababcd'.lstrip('ab') -> 'cd'`.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Didn't think about that! I've added the edits. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Eddy Oh ohh. I've added a similar solution using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can we go like this:

```
s='abbcddba'
e='b'
c=0
for a in s:
    if e==a:
        c=c+1
print(c)
```