# How to count the number of letters in a word?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create a program where if you input a word, it will print out each letter of the word and how many times the letter appears in that word.

Eg; when I input "aaaarggh", the output should be "a 4 r 1 g 2 h 1".

```
def compressed (word):
    count = 0
    index = 0
    while index < len(word):
        letter = word[index]
        for letter in word:
            index = index + 1
            count = count + 1
            print(letter, count)
        break

print("Enter a word:")
word = input()
compressed(word)
```

So far it just prints out each letter and position in the word. 
Any help appreciated, thank you!

(no using dict method)

Comment: Can you use `collections.Counter`? Because it does exactly what you want! (`from collections import Counter; Counter("aaaarggh")`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting each letter's frequency in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806866/counting-each-letters-frequency-in-a-string)

Comment: As an aside - [`str`'s are sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) and can be iterated - `for character in word: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a="aaaarggh"
d={}
for char in set(a):
    d[char]=a.count(char)
print(d)
```

output

```
{'a': 4, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'g': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just type (for Python 2.7+):

```
import collections
dict(collections.Counter('aaaarggh'))
```

having:

```
{'a': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 1, 'r': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, You can use counter it will return dict type

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter("aaaarggh"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of implementing it using a `dict`:

```
def compressed(word):
    letters = dict()
    for c in word:
        letters[c] = letters.get(c, 0) + 1
    for key, value in letters.items():
        print(f'{value}{key}', end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you can do this easily with a `dict` !

```
test_input = "aaaarggh"

def compressed (word):
  letter_dict = {}
  for letter in test_input:
    if letter not in letter_dict:
      letter_dict[letter] = 1
    else:
      letter_dict[letter] = letter_dict[letter]+1
  return letter_dict

print(compressed(test_input))
```

Outputs:

```
{'a': 4, 'r': 1, 'g': 2, 'h': 1}
```

Comment: What exactly is a dict? I'm still a student so the skills we are taught are quite limited

Comment: A `dict` (or dictionary) is a data structure that holds key-value pairs - you can see more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries . They are pretty useful! Happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` is concise. But here's an alternative using `defaultdict`, which is a subclass of `dict`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

test_input = "aaaarggh"

d = defaultdict(int)
for letter in test_input:
    d[letter] += 1
```

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Answer (score -1):

```
def counter(word):
    
    dic ={}
    for i in [*word]:
        counter = word.count(i)
        d={i:counter}
        dic.update(d)
    return dic

counter("aaaarggh")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).