# count characters of a string using function

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

Write a function named count_letters that takes as a parameter a string and returns a dictionary that tabulates how many of each letter is in that string. The string can contain characters other than letters, but only the letters should be counted. The string could even be the empty string. Lower-case and upper-case versions of a letter should be part of the same count. The keys of the dictionary should be the upper-case letters. If a letter does not appear in the string, then it would not get added to the dictionary. For example, if the string is

```
"AaBb"
```

then the dictionary that is returned should contain these key-value pairs:

```
{'A': 2, 'B': 2}
```

```
def count_letters(string):
    """counts all the letters in a given string"""
    your_dict = dict()
    for x in string:
        x = x.upper()  # makes lowercase upper
        if x not in your_dict:
            your_dict[x]= 1
        else:
            your_dict[x] += 1
    return your_dict
```

I am getting the following error when I go to upload:

```
Test Failed: {'Q': 1, 'U': 3, 'I': 3, 'S': 6, ' ': 3, 'C[48 chars]': 1} != {'S': 6, 'U': 3, 'I': 3, 'T': 3, 'O': 3, 'C[32 chars]': 1}
+ {'C': 2, 'D': 2, 'E': 2, 'I': 3, 'O': 3, 'P': 1, 'Q': 1, 'S': 6, 'T': 3, 'U': 3}
- {' ': 3,
-  '?': 1,
-  'C': 2,
-  'D': 2,
-  'E': 2,
-  'I': 3,
-  'O': 3,
-  'P': 1,
-  'Q': 1,
-  'S': 6,
-  'T': 3,
-  'U': 3}
```

Comment: Did you try fixing the indentation? Every line from line 6 to the end should be indented with a tab to the right.

Comment: Change `your_dict[x]= 0` to `your_dict[x]= 1`

Comment: I have it indented in the correct code .. my bad it copied over weird! also, I tried changing it to 1 and I still get the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting each letter's frequency in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806866/counting-each-letters-frequency-in-a-string)

Comment: @SanV could you explain/ tell me what I need to remove or change so it doesn't duplicate it?

Comment: @ellezi: Justin's fix should fix your code, but we can't be sure, since the code you posted needs its indentation fixed as well. Your output looked correct (except all the values were one lower than they should have been), so just changing the initialization value on first occurrence of a new letter is all it should need.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, with fixing the code (it just copied over wrong in the initial post) and adding Justin 's comment about the 0 to 1 I still get the following error: Test Failed: {'Q': 1, 'U': 3, 'I': 3, 'S': 6, ' ': 3, 'C[48 chars]': 1} != {'S': 6, 'U': 3, 'I': 3, 'T': 3, 'O': 3, 'C[32 chars]': 1}
+ {'C': 2, 'D': 2, 'E': 2, 'I': 3, 'O': 3, 'P': 1, 'Q': 1, 'S': 6, 'T': 3, 'U': 3}
- {' ': 3,
-  '?': 1,
-  'C': 2,
-  'D': 2,
-  'E': 2,
-  'I': 3,
-  'O': 3,
-  'P': 1,
-  'Q': 1,
-  'S': 6,
-  'T': 3,
-  'U': 3}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  Feel free to adjust it to your requirements:

```
import collections
def count_letters(string):
    return collections.Counter(string.upper())

print(count_letters('Google'))

Output:  Counter({'G': 2, 'O': 2, 'L': 1, 'E': 1})
```

For documentation of the Counter dict subclass in collections module, [check this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Update without using `collections` module:

```
def count_letters(string):
    your_dict={}
    for i in string.upper(): 
        if i in your_dict: 
            your_dict[i] += 1
        else: 
            your_dict[i] = 1
    return your_dict  

Output: {'G': 2, 'O': 2, 'L': 1, 'E': 1}
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't think I am allowed to use those codes of counter and import collections; im just in an intro level comp sci class

Comment: Side-note: Never put the import in the function itself. Python's import machinery can be surprisingly heavyweight; it's cheaper when the module has already been imported, but paying the cost on every use when you could just import it once globally and reuse it is generally not worth it unless the import is really expensive, and many programs will never call the function (saving the cost of the import entirely).

Comment: @ShadowRanger agreed and thanks for pointing it out.  I will remove it from inside the function

Comment: On top of what @ShadowRanger said, it’s also a matter of code style. In fact, I had never even considered the performance aspect, so I’m glad to have learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

This solution *does* use `collections`, but unlike with `Counter` we aren’t getting the entire solution from a single library function. I hope it’s permitted, and if it isn’t, that it will at least be informative in some way.

```py
import collections as colls

def count_letters(str_in):
    str_folded = str_in.casefold()
    counts = colls.defaultdict(int)
    for curr_char in str_folded:
        counts[curr_char] += 1
    return counts
```

[`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is extremely practical. As the name indicates, when we try to index a dictionary with a key that doesn’t exist, it creates a default value for that key and carries out our original operation. In this case, since we declare that our `defaultdict` will use integers for its keys, the default value is 0.

[`str.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) is a method designed specifically for the complex problem that is case-insensitive comparison. While it is unlikely to make a difference here, it’s a good function to know.

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score -1):

Without using `collections`, here is a solution:

```
def count_letters(string):
    string = string.upper()
    counts = {}
    for a in set(string):
        counts[a] = string.count(a)
    return counts
```

This function iterates over `set(string)`, which is equal to all the letters used in your word, without duplicates, and in uppercase. Then it counts how many times each letter appears in your string, and adds it to your `counts` dictionary.

I hope this answers your question. :)

Comment: Isn’t this incredibly inefficient?

Comment: I don't see how. Could you tell me how you see it as inefficient? I would have thought it to be more efficient, as it doesn't need to iterate as many times as it would if `string` had been left as a `str` rather than a `set`.

Comment: Every `count` operation iterates over the entire string. If the string has `n` unique characters, that’s n + 1 iterations, versus 1 iteration for most solutions.

Comment: In OP’s situation, I doubt that it will make any difference (although I am curious, I’ll try to run some quick benchmarks tomorrow). It’s a matter of learning good principles and habits.